# Javascript printing html tags as part of innerHTML output to screen

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript segment that prints output to a div.

```
output.textContent = "";
for(i=0; i<14; i++){
    output.append(document.createElement("p").innerHTML = net_words(sonnet[i]));
    output.append(document.createElement("br"));
  }
```

The function `net_words` that generates the output is as follows:

```
function net_words(line) {
  var net_line = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
  var ret = ""
  if (net_line != 1) {
    ret += "<span class=\"netno\">"
    ret += line
  }
  else {
    var net_list = line.split(" ")
    var rand_word = Math.floor(Math.random() * net_list.length)
    ret += "<span class=\"netno\">"
    for (var i=0; i<net_list.length; i++) {
      if (i == rand_word) {
        ret += "<span class=\"netyes\">"
        ret += net_list[i]
        ret += " "
        ret += "</span>"
      }
      else {
        ret += net_list[i]
        ret += " "
      }
    }
  }
  ret += "</span>"
  return ret
}
```

The problem is, it prints the line as follows:

```
<span class="netno">From fairest creatures we desire increase</span>
```

That is, it prints it with the HTML tag visible, rather than applied to the code. When I paste it into the text editor for stack overflow, it prints as normal (no tags) unless I put it as a code snippet. What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
output.append(document.createElement("p").innerHTML = net_words(sonnet[i]));
```

You think that you appended `<p>`, but in fact you appended the result of the assignment. To fix it do:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = net_words(sonnet[i]);
output.append(p);
```

or

```
output.innerHTML += '<p>' + net_words(sonnet[i]) + '</p>';
```